# Import database

Tags: database, postgresql, import, zip

I have a zip file with contains multiple text files. I need to import it into a Postgres database. Watched some YouTube videos, read articles about it. It didn't help. How to import all files into a database?

Comment: what is the prefix of the files ?

Comment: You will need to provide example data showing the content of the files. Also what generated the files in the first place? Add information as update to your question.

Comment: How exactly did you try to import the files? Additionally, you need to provide table definition (ddl script). Please spend a few minutes and take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow) and review [ask].